# TranslateException: The request is missing a valid API key

Tags: android, google-translate, google-translation-api

I did everything following the [example](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java), but I get an error.

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
                  {
                    "code" : 403,
                    "errors" : [ {
                      "domain" : "global",
                      "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
                      "reason" : "forbidden"
                    } ],
                    "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
                    "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
                  }
```

Through the command line everything [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fciUG.png), but does not work in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged this question with "android". It is worthwhile mentioning that Cloud Java client libraries do not currently support Android. This is documented on the "Translation API Client Libraries" [page](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunatelly now it's possible to use Translation API with Android, see https://medium.com/@yeksancansu/how-to-use-google-translate-api-in-android-studio-projects-7f09cae320c7